# Creating multiple functional buttons on application start up

Tags: java, button, methods

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my mind around how to get my program to assign action commands/action listening to a group of buttons created from a stack. The buttons are created from lines on a text file.

```
public void getLaunchButtons(){


    File list = new File("resources/programs.txt");

    String line = null;

    try{

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(list);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        buttons = new Stack<Button>();

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        buttons.push(new Button(line));
        add(buttons.pop());

        }

        br.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

How could I go about assigning an Action Listener to the buttons that are created?
My overall goal is to create buttons that when clicked launch the program associated to that button. The user will be able to add program titles (button title) and the directory to the program to be launched (button action command)

Comment: You have to better format code, empty lines is not readable anyway the code has a minimufal sense.

Comment: Its spaced out because I was in the process of figuring out mynext step. after a section of my code is all figured out, i always clean it up and add comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic stuff, get the reference to the Button instead of trying to stick it straight into the stack.

```
Button b = new Button(line);
b.addActionListener(referenceToActionListener);
buttons.push(b);
add(b);
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. That's what happens when you move too fast. Haha.

Comment: Did I over-complicate things a bit? I'm thinking I can loose the stack.

Comment: Yea, I don't see a reason for the stack, unless you want to keep the button references for later processing.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Button b = new Button(line);
b.addActionListener(listener);
add(b);

//In global
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        JButton button = (JButton)actionEvent.getSource();
        String line = button.getText();
 }
};
```